# f.read() does not read between lines

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I use Python 3.6. I have some strings I want to check in a read.txt file. The problem is that the .txt file is written such that sentences may be cut and put into a different line. For example:

```
bla bla bla internal control over financial reporting or an attestation
report of our auditors
```

The .txt file cuts the sentence after the word "attestation" and starts with "report" in the following line. I want to look for the entire sentence in the file, irrespective of what line it is (and create var1=1 if the sentence is in the file, and 0 otherwise).

I use the following code to parse (and it seems I don't know how to specify that I don't bother about lines):

```
string1 = 'internal control over financial reporting or an attestation report of our auditors'    
exemptions = []
for eachfile in file_list: #I have many .txt files in my directory
        with open(eachfile, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            line2 = f.read()  # line2 should be a var with all the .txt file
            var1 = re.findall(str1, line2, re.I)  # find str1 in line2
            if len(re.findall(str1, line2, re.I)) > 0:
                exemptions.append('1')  # if it detects smthg, then append exemptions list with var1=1
            else:
                exemptions.append('0')  # otherwise var1= 0
```

Any idea of how to do that? I thought that by using the line2=f.read(), I was actually checking the whole .txt file, irrespective of lines, but it does not seem so....

Thank you anyways!

Comment: As @asongtoruin said, when the file is read, it reads the sentence with a `\n` between  `attestation` and `report`, meaning that this needs to be replaced with a space, `' '` as otherwise the sentence will have a `\n` which does not match your `regex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assuming a newline is the same as a space - it's not. Try changing

```
line2 = f.read()
```

to

```
line2 = f.read().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' ')
```

This should replace any newlines in the file with spaces, thus allowing your search to work as intended.

You could similarly do

```
line2 = ' '.join(line.rstrip('\n') for line in f)
```

You could instead modify your regex:

```
var1 = re.findall(str1.replace(' ', '\s+'), line2, re.I)  # find str1 in line2
if var1:
    exemptions.append('1')
else:
    exemptions.append('0')
```

In regex terms, `\s` is any spacing character, `\s+` allows for multiple spaces or newlines.

Comment: I assume you meant `.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ' ')` ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers whoops! Read sub in the regex and got overexcited, good spot.

Comment: @MoeA agreed - putting it in

Comment: `' '.join(f.readlines())` wont solve the problem - `splitlines()` keeps the lineseps at the end of strings. You want `' '.join(line.rstrip("\n") for line in f)` (which also avoids copying the whole file content twice in memory).

Comment: Thanks so much! In the end I went for the line2= ' '.join(line.rstrip('\n') for line in f) solution and it worked smooth on my code!